# react button no response or display any message when clicked

Tags: reactjs

I try to click button to test the it was clicked or not?
But I found it no response when i click it, is that I missing something?

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {

  switchNameHandler = () =>{
    console.log('was clicked');
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Hi, I'm a React App</h1>
          <h1>Another heading</h1>
          <button onClick={this.switchNameHandler()}>Switch Names</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try changing your button to:

```
<button onClick={() => this.switchNameHandler()}>Switch Names</button>
```

this should invoke the call when the button is clicked

Comment: Yes. Is work! but why need to  using "() =>" to invoke the call? Is that a default for using it as onclick function?

Comment: It isn't necessarily the default for using the onClick since you could also simply write:

<button onClick={this.switchNameHandler}>Switch Names</button>

But that would required you handling the event. For more info on event handling with React I'd recommend checking out the docs. They do a much better job than I ever could on explaining the differences in syntax:

https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html